# Analysis of ordinal data with multiple assessments per unit... the right approach?

Tags: repeated-measures, ordinal-data, agreement-statistics

Suppose I have a dataset with the following information:

- N objects, each of which can be rated
- The number of ratings per object is variable (raters are unidentified), e.g., there are 30 objects each with a unique id
- Each row has the predicted rating, the actual rating, and the difference between the two, which is an ordinal value, say between 0 and 10

How do I measure the consistency of ratings per object and for the whole dataset? Basically, there is a distribution of "differences" per object. What are the various ways to approach this problem?  Thank you.

Comment: Maybe this article could help, though I'm not sure: http://www.tqmp.org/Content/vol08-1/p023/p023.pdf

Comment: Thank you for the reference. I will check it out and post a reply here.